# undefined references when linking with static library with OTL using a makefile

Tags: c++, makefile, linker, g++

I want to link my project to a static library (msodbcsql11.lib), and I want to include it's header (msodbcsql.h) and another header file of a framework otlv4.h) using a simple makefile, but it looks like it can't find the library. Here is my makefile:

```
CC=g++
LDFLAGS=
CFLAGS=-c -Wall
SOURCES=main.cpp
LIBB = C:\temp\lib
LIBINCL = C:\temp\include
CFLAGS += -I$(LIBINCL)
LDFLAGS += -L$(LIBB)
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
EXECUTABLE=main
all: $(SOURCES) $(EXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $@

.cpp.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

And here is my c++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
#define OTL_ODBC_MSSQL_2008 // Compile OTL 4/ODBC, MS SQL 2008
#include <otlv4.h>

int main(){
    otl_connect db; //undefined reference errors
}
```

Here is the build when I declared otl_connect:

```
18:42:33 **** Incremental Build of configuration Default for project mak ****
make all 
g++ -c -Wall -IC:\temp\include main.cpp -o main.o
g++  -LC:\temp\lib main.o -o main
main.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN8otl_connD1Ev[_ZN8otl_connD1Ev]+0x66): undefined reference to `SQLFreeHandle'
main.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN8otl_connD1Ev[_ZN8otl_connD1Ev]+0x66): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `SQLFreeHandle'
main.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN8otl_connD1Ev[_ZN8otl_connD1Ev]+0x9e): undefined reference to `SQLFreeHandle'
main.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN8otl_connD1Ev[_ZN8otl_connD1Ev]+0x9e): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `SQLFreeHandle'
main.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN8otl_conn6logoffEv[_ZN8otl_conn6logoffEv]+0x54): undefined reference to `SQLDisconnect'
main.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN8otl_conn6logoffEv[_ZN8otl_conn6logoffEv]+0x54): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `SQLDisconnect'
main.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN8otl_conn5errorER7otl_exc[_ZN8otl_conn5errorER7otl_exc]+0x70): undefined reference to `SQLGetDiagRec'
main.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN8otl_conn5errorER7otl_exc[_ZN8otl_conn5errorER7otl_exc]+0x70): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `SQLGetDiagRec'
main.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN8otl_conn6commitEv[_ZN8otl_conn6commitEv]+0x23): undefined reference to `SQLEndTran'
main.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN8otl_conn6commitEv[_ZN8otl_conn6commitEv]+0x23): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `SQLEndTran'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
makefile:14: recipe for target 'main' failed
make: *** [main] Error 1

18:42:35 Build Finished (took 1s.993ms)
```

What is wrong with my makefile? What should I do?

edit: I updated based on @Jonathan Wakely's answer:

```
LIBB = C:\temp\lib
LIBFILE = msodbcsql11
LDFLAGS += -L$(LIBB) -l$(LIBFILE)
```

I'm still getting the same errors

Update: Updated makefile as suggested by @Jonathan Wakely, but still getting errors. BTW, I changed the file format of libmsodbcsql11.lib to libmsodbcsql11.a because the compiler can't detect the .lib version

```
CC=g++
LDFLAGS=
CFLAGS=-c -Wall
SOURCES=main.cpp
LIBB = C:\temp\lib
LIBFILE = msodbcsql11
LIBINCL = C:\temp\include
CFLAGS += -I$(LIBINCL)
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
LDFLAGS += -L$(LIBB) -l$(LIBFILE)
EXECUTABLE=main

all: $(SOURCES) $(EXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(OBJECTS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@

.cpp.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

Comment: Where did you specify your ODBC layer library?  Those functions that can't be found are generic ODBC function calls, and you need a library (similar to `odbc32.lib` for Visual C++) to provide this layer.

Comment: @morbidCode You're not specifying anywhere that you want to link with `msodbcsql11.lib`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie isn't it the msodbcsql11.lib? Sorry I'm extremely new at this

Comment: Yes, but you haven't mentioned that anywhere in the makefile! How is the linker supposed to know you want to link to that library?

Comment: By longstanding convention, `CC` is a c compiler, while `CXX` is the C++ compiler.  By assigning CC=g++ you break many traditions and confuse your readers.  Also, perhaps more importantly, you confuse `make`, and render many implicit rules useless.

Comment: @William Pursell thanks. I'm not so familiar with conventions because I'm new at this.

Comment: @morbidCode That is precisely why I made the comment!

Comment: @morbidCode, and please realize that you are not alone in this regard.  You will see many, many, (unfortunately *very* many) examples of really bad Makefiles.  By learning some conventions (read http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/make.html#tag_20_76) you will instantly be more knowledgable than 98% of the people who write makefiles!

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie you're right I need that odbc32.lib for it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-L` flag only tells the linker where to look for libraries, you need to use `-l` to tell it which library to link to.

Comment: Ok, I changed to this: I created the variable LIBFILE for the library. LIBB = C:\temp\lib LIBFILE = msodbcsql11 LDFLAGS += -L$(LIBB) -l$(LIBFILE), I'm
still getting the same errors.

Comment: Like this? $(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS) $(CC) $(OBJECTS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ is that the linker command?

Comment: Yess, the `$(CC) $(OBJECTS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@` part.

Comment: still the same. I'm going to post the full updated makefile. Maybe there's another problem.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with my current makefile! I'm using the wrong library, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This might be helpful...

Apparently the [OTL library](http://otl.sourceforge.net/) requires the odbc32.lib file to call ODBC functions. It's a little confusing because the microsoft ODBC driver have this msodbcsql11.lib, apparently it is not what's needed. Regardless the previous versions of my makefile did not call any library, so I accepted @Jonathan Wakely's answer.